# TypeError: Complaint.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im getting this error:
`TypeError: ComplaintData.get is not a function`

Could somebody tell me please why it's showing that error? What could cause this error? The service is injected into the controller but i dont know what could be causing the error.

Controller:

```
(() => {

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('complaintController', complaintController)

  complaintController.$inject = ['$http', '$rootScope', 'Complaint']

  function complaintController($rootScope, Complaint) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.array = [];

    Complaint.get()
      .success((info) => {
        vm.array = data              
      })
      .error(() => {
        $scope.error = data
      })
.................
```

Service:

```
(() => {
  angular
    .module('app')
    .service('Complaint', complaintInfoService)

    function complaintInfoService($http) {

      function getInfo() {
        return http.get('/user/info/')
      }

      function createComplaint(data) {
        return $http.post('/user/complaints', {data: data})
      }

      return {
        get: getInfo,
        create: createComplaint
      } 
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your controller you forgot to declare the $http variable

```
function complaintController($http, $rootScope, Complaint) //add $http in front
```

now you are trying to access the get method from $rootscope

Comment: Now it's giving me: `ReferenceError: http is not defined
    at Object.getInfo [as get]` @eltonkamami

Comment: @KemalP. on `Complaint.getInfo` you dont have a $ in front of http

Comment: I do, @eltonkamami

Comment: @KemalP. from your service snippet `function getInfo() { return http.get('/user/info/') }`. `$` missing

Comment: oh, thanks... will accept the answer in several mins